# Getting error while uploading csv file using phpExcel

Tags: php, csv

I am new to php, When I am trying to upload a csv file which is having nearly 37k rows and file size is 2.7M.B I am getting an error like

```
Error loading file "": Could not open  for reading! File does not exist.
```

Even I tried to increase "upload_max_filesize" in ini file.This is upload max file is also not working. When I remove some 10k records from that csv file then it is working fine.

```
try 
    {
        $inputFileType = 'CSV';
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objReader = $objReader->setDelimiter(";");
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }
```

It is stopping here. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Pls can you show how you set $file ?

Comment: $file = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];

Comment: as said in the error  `file "" ` doesn't exists

Comment: But when i remove 10k reocords from csv  then it is working fine

Comment: how do you create `$file`? Show us the code

Comment: this file is generating from an internal system.

Comment: So basically you have the error if you reduce the file size and not if you don't ? are you sure you do not change php code also ? The error you get looks like it should fail all the time, the behavior you describe looks like a timeout. Something isn't clear

Comment: No, only issue is if I have 37k records...otherwise everything works fine, no change in the code

Comment: is there any way to increase memory size with in phpexcel?

Comment: It looks like a upload limit problem. Set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini. Not only upload_max_filesize.

Comment: your problem is not there, your problem is when you create the `$file`, as you can see when you have 37k records the `$file` isn't initialized ( `$file=""`)

Comment: I did it, it is working in  my local system , but not working on server, even I have changed both upload max size and post max size to 50M

Comment: are you already move uploaded file? because `$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];` is still in temporary with random name.